# Merging Objective-C project to Swift; what's the best method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to migrate our large Objective-C-based iOS project to Swift. So what's the best way: Import Swift files into Objective-C, or import the Objective-C project into a fresh new Swift project? What will be the fastest ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

After time I spent of the project migration to the Swift I can say that it is no silver bullet in this question. It is really depending on the flow that is set-app in the team that you are working.

From my point of view and experience you should take existing  project and start to write all new logic using Swift and in parallel try to rewrite business lawyers of the application in the modern way. For example network layer, database layer. In this way you reduce regression of the application and receive controlled migration flow.

**Pros:**

- New logic will be in Swift.
- Step by step migration will balance
  regression.
- Suport of legacy code that impossible to rewrite to Swift
- Writing code in Swift way (Protocols, Function, Generics, Structures)

**Cons**:

- Time
- Regression of the app
- Quite big rewriting of the code.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! So now, we have many solutions with explanation, I will ask my team to choose the best method for us. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting a fresh project with the aim to only use Swift in the future, then I would create a new Swift project and then link to your Objective-C framework. This is what we did where I work, and slowly over time we have been deleting from the Objective-C project anything that is not being used. This may not be quicker than importing everything into the same project, but will give your code some separation from the old Objective-C code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the fast response ! But, which is the least restrictive ? And the fastest ? But yes, in terms we want to only have a Swift App

Comment: I did not find the method I suggested very restrictive. And it is a rather quick process, besides importing any headers that you may need in the Swift project. But instead of the fastest, I think you should consider what will be better for you in the future. It probably would be quicker to import all the Objective-C code into your new project, but then you would have a lot of legacy code hanging around in your new project.

Comment: Great Thanks. So we will think with these element to make our choice !

Answer (score 1):

It's a very complex question and the answer is: Depends... 
I think there are a few questions to make before answer yours:

- Is your project "open", your team is developing new features on the same code base? or has a solid and reliable code base and just a little changes?
- Can your company afford a "NEW VERSION" entirely made in Swift with new engineering?

Basically, make a big refactor (as language migration) involves a re-engineering job too, most things will not work if you just transcript the code base and if you do so, you are losing all the Swift benefits and there is no Win situation to change your code.

In my point of view, creating a new project is just a good thing to do if you will make a new version of your app. Is cleaner, is better, but like I've said there will be a lot of job and re-engineering.

Otherwise, just embed Swift code into an Objective-C running app, will cause a lot of trouble and confusion. But is faster and you can continue with new features and implementing improvements on your app.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Now we will choose the best method for us with this elements ! :)

Answer (score 1):

So, here is my 2 cents to your problem:
I would recommend slow code conversion or rather refactoring to Swift if required for new code parts.
Furthermore, if the converted code is currently being used in other side projects (feature branches etc.) you could not ensure that it would still work accordingly.

I hope you got unit tests in place, because those could make life easiert. Anyway, consider the aspect of regression testing of your application's features. Libraries you use, would now have to be frameworks (some Libraries might not compile as Framework, be aware of that).

IF you really want to convert the code base, I would do this hirarchically.

1. Consider an entire Application Layer and within this layer
   specific classes.
2. Start writing tests for those classes (you can do that in Swift, too), Unit Test, Integration Test, UI Tests
3. Convert the class to a swift class (be aware that some logic might change and other functions would be affected, too)
4. Implement bridging header (if necessary) that you can use as Application Layer interface to the other interfaces - this would even improve your understanding of the different code parts play together. If you notice some weird declarations. Stuff being public, too much random accesses fro different classes or something. Don't touch that yet. In fact, note that down
5. Perform extensive tests of your small change
6. Start over again with the next class
7. If all classes have finished on your current Application Layer and you broke nothing. Good job. Now have a look for your notes.
8. Continue with the next layer.

In Short: I would only convert those parts to Swift that need to be changed anyway (refactoring, new features, bugs, whatever). If the code was working, and you don't see another reason than "well, now it is Swift", I would only take the conversion into account, if I really had time for that, else you might break working code or even the architecture that was setup, which differs for Swift and Objective-C in some ways.

If you really feel like you are the man for this: I would start to write tests ;-)
Unit-, Integration and UI Tests. This will help you with your CURRENT code base, but also with your future code base, whether is in Objective-C or Swift.
And it is a great help for converting the code into Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to import the Objective-C project into a fresh new Swift. Because you can use [objective c to swift converter](http://objectivec2swift.com). It saves thousands of work hours.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.